# Imported XML-Documentation missing for C# Function with .NET dictionary<String, Value> input type in OpenEdge Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openedge, progress-4gl, xml-documentation

I have searched, but found nothing that covers this.

My Problem: In OpenEdge Progress Developer Studio, I have imported a .dll and the corresponding Xml documentation file from an C# application. The written function commentary of the documentation should now be visible in "Class Browser" in the OpenEdge Editor.

But the documentation for C# functions that have an .NET `dictionary<String, Object>` type as input-variable is missing. *(All the functions work and the documentation is showing for the rest of the functions)*

Example of my C# function in Visual Studio:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary Text of my function
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Something remarkable</remarks>
/// <param name="mydictionary">dict description</param>
/// <returns>String Return</returns>
public String TestFunctionWInputDictionary(dictionary<String, object> mydictionary)
{
    do something ...
}
```

My steps:

1. For my C# application in Visual Basic (V16.9.3), i am generating the .dll File and the XML-Documentation file.

The XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<assembly>
<name>Namespacename</name>
</assembly>
<members>
<member name="M:Namespacename.Classname.TestFunctionWInputDictionary(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary{System.String,System.Object})">
<summary>Summary Text of my function</summar>
<remarks>Something remarkable</remarks>
<param name="mydictionary">dict description</param>
<returns>String Return</returns>
</member>
</members>
</doc>
```

2. In my 4gl Progress application in OpenEdge Progress Developer Studio (V4.5.2) I am importing those files into the Assemblies folder.

After "rebuilding the assembly project model" in OpenEdge Editor, I can use the imported functions and see the documentation in the "Class Browser". But NOT for the functions that have an dictionary as input-variable.

This is how it looks in OpenEdge Editor "Class Browser":

```
METHOD PUBLIC FINAL character TestFunctionWInputDictionary(INPUT mydictionary AS CLASS "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<character, System.Object>")

Member of Namespacename.Classname

Summary:
```

But it should look like this:

```
METHOD PUBLIC FINAL character TestFunctionWInputDictionary(INPUT mydictionary AS CLASS "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<character, System.Object>")

Member of Namespacename.Classname

Summary: Summary Text of my function

Remarks: Something remarkable

Parameters:
mydictionary: dict description

Return Values:
String Return
```

When I remove the dictionary input variable the documentation shows up. The Xml File shows no warnings (like e.g. Not well formed)

I don't know if this is an XML problem or an OpenEdge Editor or Progress problem.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a functional limitation (aka bug) of the Class Browser in Progress Developer Studio. I would contact Progress technical support.

Calling those methods should work though.